# Excel VBA Arrays good practices: create a huge blank array at once or use redim preserve all the time?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I like to use an array as if it was an "in RAM memory" spreadsheet, so the code is more clean and it runs faster.

So I would like to ask: generally, is it better start the code with a huge array, say `Dim arr(10000)`, so I can work with it as if it was a blank sheet I fill when necessary, or is that a bad practice, and, instead, I should use `Redim Preserve` all the time I need to insert data into the array?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: id say if you've got the memory no harm. the code will be simpler.

Comment: In general, best practice is probably to properly dimension the array in the first place so that no `ReDim Preserve` is necessary.  If that isn't possible for some reason, there's no real harm in making the array larger than it needs to be.  Performance wise, over-sizing the array is definitely favorable to multiple `ReDim Preserve` statements.

Comment: In many cases you are able to calculate/count how big your array will be before you start filling it. That wouly be the best solution as you can dimension your array correctly, but it highly depends on the code and what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: In any case i can, i would use a dictionary. In all other cases (direct read of sheet range) i'd use a range. The downside of dictionary is every entry (key) has to be unique, the upside compared to arrays, you can remove, add, look if exists... last downside of dictionaries, the item cannot be a udt (user defined type) , even if it can accept objects, so i find that odd.

Comment: The right way to mimic a growing list of values is to dynamically inflate an array by doubling its size when it is full and by keeping the count of values (`If Count > UBound(arr) Then Redim Preserve arr(Ubound(arr) * 2)`). This is how it's done in the Java and .Net framework. There's no need to start with a big array since you won't notice the different compared to a small one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on how you intend to fill the array (noting that this is in the context of Excel). Here are four simple scenarios:

**Filling from a Range.** Simply `Dim` a Variant and let VBA do all the work.

```
Dim myArray as Variant
Dim myRange as Range

'Set myRange = something
myArray = myRange.Value '<-- Fills a 2-D array
For rowIterator = LBound(myArray,1) to UBound(myArray,1) '<- How identify the size of the first dimension
    For colIterator = LBound(myArray,2) to UBound(myArray,2) '<- How identify the size of the second dimension
        'Do something to myArray(rowIterator, colIterator)
    Next colIterator
Next rowIterator
```

**Filling when you define your bounds.** In some code, you can learn early in the code running what your bounds are going to be. In this case, you can `ReDim` before you get into a loop.

```
Dim myArray() As String
Dim someCounter As Long
'Some early code
someCounter = CLng(myRange.Value)
ReDim myArray(someCounter) '<-- Do this only once.
For iterator = LBound(myArray) to UBound(myArray)
    ' Do Something to myArray(iterator)
Next iterator
```

**Filling within a loop.** Avoid this when ever you can as `ReDim`ming an array, especially with `ReDim Preserve` is computationally expensive. However, if you know it is a small loop, you might want to accept the cost.

An alternative to resizing in a loop is to use a `Collection`.

**Oversizing to start with.** Rather than continually re-dimensioning the array, you could oversize the array but you then have the additional management overhead of trying to manage the unused array slots. How do you know if the value in the array of "" or 0 is really "" or 0 instead of a default null value?